# How to get the Payload from saga action other than with function isType()?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-saga

I define action like this

```
public static readonly logout = actionCreator<{
  foo: bar,
}>('logout');
```

Action has its payload {foo: bar} how to withdraw the Payload type from action so i can use it later in some general function? Like

```
someGeneralFunction<Payload>(action: Action, payload: Payload) {
   // i dont want to do this:
   if (isType(action, logout)) {
   }

   // because i somehow passed the action to the function so i know
   // the payload
}

someGeneralFunction<logout>(action)
```

I want to do general Saga watch_xyz handler or function factory where i pass only few arguments like specific action etc.

Or i want to use the isType() dynamically but keep the typescript check of the payload.